# Question about STS installation

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded STS 64 bit version , but not sure what are the steps to install on Ubuntu 12.04 
Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

That might be a question to direct at the STS folks.
But [this](http://installspringlinux.blogspot.se/2013/05/linux-ubuntu-raring-i386-howto-install-gettingstarted-springtoolsuite.html) MAY give a hint or two.